# How to access inner text in DOM tree with VBA

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, dom, web-scraping

I am writing a macro to access some text in the DOM tree of a website but I cannot seem to get access to the text. Please see attached image for the html section in question and see attached code for what I have so far. Any help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
Sub DoThings(ieapp As Object)
    Dim match_status As String
    Dim projection_rows As Object

    With ieapp
        Set projection_rows = .document.getElementById("div1").getElementById("div1_row_section").getElementById("tblMain").getElementById("div1_trans_row")

        match_status = projection_rows.getElementsByTagName("td")(2).getElementsByTagName("font")(0).getElementsByTagName("b")(0).innerText
        MsgBox (match_status)
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Try `ieapp.document.getElementById("div1_trans_row").getElementsByTagName("td")(2).innerText`

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Use the snippet tool via [edit] so some of us can copy paste for testing.

Comment: If you try to provide the link of your web page or sample HTML code than we can try to make a test with it and try to provide some suggestions that can help to access desired value. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using IE you can use [:nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) css pseudo class selector to specify row and column of table (first row, third column). I first select the table by id; the # is a css [id selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors). The space between each part of the string between "" represent [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)s,  meaning that each string to the right is a child of the element returned by the css selector, string, to the left. Css selectors are applied via [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector), returning a single node, and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectoraLL), returning a nodeList. In this case, they are methods of [HTMLDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument).

```
ie.document.querySelector("#tblMain tr:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(3)").innerText
```